# Framework7 - Where is the iOS colors file located?

Tags: html-framework-7

I can't seem to find where the `framework7.ios.colors.min.css` file is located. Could someone point me to where it is?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed ios.colors.css, you should find it in your css/lib path.
I'm using Framework7 with Cordova so my folders look like this:
[image]

Hope this helps...